# How to query records with rom-sql by json column in postgres?

Tags: ruby, rom-rb, rom-sql

Having a table with jsonb column containing some array,
what is best way to select records containing specific tag with `rom-sql`?

Example of query.
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u4CFkUUpnHZj67j1RJ5YRe/0

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  id INT,
  tags JSONB
);
INSERT INTO posts (id, tags) VALUES (1, '["cats", "dogs"]');
INSERT INTO posts (id, tags) VALUES (2, '["dogs"]');

SELECT * FROM posts WHERE tags @> '["cats"]';
```

So, how to build this query with `rom-sql`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as `posts.where { tags.contain(['cats']) }`. There are some problems with obtaining YARD for these methods because we're kind of too innovative. Anyhow, the whole list of currently supported methods/operators is [on Github](https://github.com/rom-rb/rom-sql/blob/32427bec58f206c0b6cc014198d599a0fff7ff03/lib/rom/sql/extensions/postgres/types/json.rb#L31-L165).